# Как обработать только видимые на листе строки?

Tags: google-spreadsheet, google-apps-script

- К таблице применен фильтр.
- На листе остались 6 видимых строк под номерами: `1`,`2`,`3`,`5`,`9`,`200`.
- Эти строки выделили для дальнейшей обработки в скрипте.

Скрипт ниже получает массив данных, соответствующий области выделения.

```
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
var selection = sheet.getActiveRange();
var fromRow = selection.getRow();
var toRow = selection.getLastRow();
var fromColumn = 1;
var toColumn = 7;

var array = sheet.getRange(fromRow, fromColumn, toRow, toColumn).getValues();
var selected_rows = array.length + 1;
```

- Ожидаемый результат: **selected_rows = 6**.
- Полученный результат: **selected_rows = 200**.

То есть метод `getRange` получает данные из области выделения, не учитывая результаты фильтрации.

Как обработать только видимые на листе строки?

Comment: Есть обсуждение тут. https://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=195
Но, может уже есть решение....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
/* --------------------------------------------------------------

  возвращает массив видимых строк в границах заданной области

----------------------------------------------------------------- */ 
function getVisibleData (range) {

    var values = range.getValues();
    var selection = range.getSheet().getActiveRange();
    var row1 = selection.getRow();
    var row2 = selection.getLastRow()-row1+1;

    var range2 = range.getSheet().getRange(row1, 1, row2); 
    var arrData = [], colors = [];

    // обрабатываем только видимые строки (работа в условиях включенной  фильтрации на листе)
    // запоминаем текущие цвета
    var oldColors = range2.getFontColors();

    // меняем цвета на новые
    for (var r = 0; r < oldColors.length; r++) colors[r] = [(oldColors[r] == '#000001') ? '#000002' : '#000001'];
    range2.setFontColors(colors); 

    // Невидимые строки не окрашиваются. Находим окрашенные и записываем в массив. 
    var newColors = range2.getFontColors();
    for (var r = 0; r < colors.length; r++) {
        if ((oldColors[r][0] !== newColors[r][0])) arrData.push(values[r]);
    }

    // возвращаем старые цвета
    range2.setFontColors(oldColors);

    // возвращаем массив видимых строк выделенного диапазона.
    return arrData;

 }
```

Comment: Использование результатов фильтра в скриптах будет нарушением видимой текущей концепции. Конечно, такой подход имеет место быть, но он имеет ряд суровых ограничений, которые делают его не универсальным. Основным подходом была и остается выборка на сервере. Другое дело, что нет возможности создавать пользовательские фильтры, но это уже другая история.

Answer (score -1):

Ну правильно, вы же руками строите range от первого выбранного до последнего выбранного, поэтому и выдает 200. Чтобы получить интересующий range, нужно взять пересечение созданного `array` с имеющимся `selection`. В Excel VBA есть метод Intersect(range,range...), в гугл-таблицах не нашел, но должен быть (нашел [вот такой запрос](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/issues/detail?id=1825), там упоминается, что есть rangeset, который умеет хотя бы с одним range пересечение делать - его можно попробовать применить). То есть если `selection` на самом деле является RangeSet, можно вызвать так:

```
var array = selection.subRangeSet(sheet.getRange(fromRow, fromColumn, toRow, toColumn)).getValues();
```

Comment: В GAS нет метода `RangeSet`.